# Django No module named path.to

Tags: django

using [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) when trying to load the url /social/connections/ I get the  following error.

```
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/user/Documents/workspace/iFetch/templates/socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html, error at line 3
No module named path.to
1   {% load socialaccount %}
2   
3   {% providers_media_js %}
4   
5
```

what does this mean, how can I fix or what I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`path.to.something` is a shorthand in documentation for "replace this with whatever your actual path is to the module". You've probably copied something verbatim, without replacing it with your actual path.

Comment: there is nothing in settings and its a fresh install of django-allauth strange. i'll check it out

Comment: Hey Jason, did you end up finding an answer to this? same thing happening to me and I'm also using django-allauth right out of the box.

Comment: Got it, used the code example in django-allauth which literally includes a `'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable', ` variable...